# AWS CodeCommit + CodePipeline on CI workflow

Tags: aws-codepipeline, aws-codebuild, aws-codecommit

what I'm trying to do is to create a following CI flow with standard AWS tools: CodeCommit -> CodePipeline (CodeBuild) so run a build when a Pull Request in CodeCommit is created.
From what I've seen so far, the pull request is from a specific branch to master and the CodePipeline then reacts and start CodeBuild.

Is it possible to do this with CodeBuild + CodePipeline for such CI workflow ? I've noticed that I have to specify exact branch in CodePipeline and I don't want to create one pipeline per user's branch, did I missed something ?

Answer (score 0):

CodePipeline is designed for post-merge validation and release automation. That is, once your pull-request has been merged CodePipeline will run the merged result through your testing, beta environment, etc. then automatically deploy changes to production.

[You can use CodeBuild directly](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/09/aws-codebuild-now-supports-building-github-pull-requests/) without CodePipeline for pre-merge (eg. pull request) validation, although only some sources are supported currently.

If you use CodeBuild for pre-merge validation, you can use CodePipeline in conjunction to test and release the merged result using the same CodeBuild project.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I've seen, there is some webhooks allowing interaction with GitHub, but I'm wondering if someone already did something similar (pre-merge integration with Jenkins for instance) ?